# What does a read lock do in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading

When using a `shared_mutex`, there is exclusive access and shared access. Exclusive access only allows one thread to access the resource while others are blocked until the thread holding the lock releases the lock. A shared access is when multiple threads are allowed to access the resource but under a "read lock". What is a "read lock"? I don't understand the meaning of a read lock. Can someone give code examples of a "read lock".

**My guess of a read lock:** I thought that a read lock only allows threads to run the code and not modify anything. Apparently I was wrong when I tried some code and it didn't work as I thought.

Again, can someone help me understand what a read lock is.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your guess is *very* close to being right but there's a slight subtlety.

The read/write distinction shows *intent* of the locker, it does not limit what the locker actually does. If a read-locker decides to modify the protected resource, it can, and hilarity will ensue. However, that's no different to a thread modifying the protected resource with no lock at all. The programmer must follow the rules, or pay the price.

---

As to the distinction, a read lock is for when you only want to *read* the shared resource. A billion different threads can do this safely because the resource is not changing while they do it.

A write lock, on the other hand, means you want to change the shared resource, so there should be *no* readers (or other writers) with an active lock.

It's a way of optimising locks based on usage. For example, consider the following lock queue, with the earliest entries on the right, and no queue jumping (readers jumping in front of writers if the writer is currently blocked) allowed:

```
(queue here) -> RR W RRRR -> (action here)
```

- The "resource controller" can allow *all* four `R` lockers at the queue head access at the same time.
- The `W` locker will then have to wait until *all* of those locks are released before gaining access.
- The final two `R` lockers must wait until the `W` locker releases but can then *both* get access concurrently.

In other words, the possible lock holders at any given time are (mutually exclusive):

- any number of readers.
- one writer.

---

As an aside, there are other possible optimisation strategies you can use as well.

For example (as alluded to earlier), you may want a reader to be able to jump the queue if it looks like the writer would have to wait a while anyway (such as there being a large number of current readers).

That's fraught with danger since you could starve a write locker, but it *can* be done provided there are limits on the number of queue jumpers.

I *have* done it in the past. From memory (a *long* ago memory of an embedded OS built in BCPL for the 6809 CPU, which shows more of my age than I probably want to), the writer included with its lock request the maximum number of queue jumpers it was happy with (defaulting to zero), and the queueing of future readers took that into account.

Comment: Before getting a write lock, all the threads with a read lock must exit the scope. It is costlier. It could be emphasized a bit more.

Comment: @Jeffrey: that would be the case if it was just a normal lock as well, but with the added cost of each reader having to wait for the previous reader to release. If it was the queue jumping aspect you were referring to, yes, that is something you want to keep an close eye on.

Answer (score 3):

A *write-lock* only allows one lock to be acquired at a time.

A read-lock only allows other *read-locks* to be acquired at the same time, but prevents *write-locks*.

If you try to acquire a *write-lock*, you will be forced to wait until every other lock (read or write) has been released. Once you have the *write-lock*, no one else can get a lock of either kind.

If you try to acquire a *read-lock*, you will have to wait for any write-lock to be released. If there is no *write-lock*, you will obtain the *read-lock*, regardless how many other threads have a read-lock.

Whether or not you modify data is entirely up to you to police. If you have a *read-lock*, you should not be modifying shared data.

Comment: Galik, just on your "If there is no write-lock, you will obtain the read-lock" comment, that's probably more of an implementation detail. If you allow read locks to proceed as long as no write lock is *active,* you risk starving the writers. I prefer to allow read-locks to succeed only if there is no currently *queued* write lock. That way, readers are still optimised in the case of no requested writers, but no starvation can occur. Then use strategies such as limited queue jumping to further optimise if desired.

Answer (score 2):

A read lock is just another way of saying that a thread of execution has acquired shared ownership of the mutex.  It says nothing about what that thread can actually *do*.

It is up to the programmer not to update whatever shared resource is being protected by the mutex under a shared lock.  To do that, acquire an exclusive lock.